# Install curl and json extension in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, curl, windows-7, composer-php

I am creating a registration form, i want to add a google captcha to the form however i noticed that the package requires PHP 5.4 or greater and "ext-curl" and "ext-json" i have looked around to try and find out how to get these dependencies installed but i have found no solution, currently when i try adding the google captcha package to my composer.json and doing a composer.update i get an error then i have to take it out from my composer.jon file and re-run composer update to fix the error.  I think it might have something to do with these 2 dependencies does anyone know how i can get them installed?

I use the inbuilt PHP server in Laravel on windows 7 platform.

Comment: I don't know anything that is named "laravel server", and neither does Google. What is this?

Comment: It's just the inbuilt PHP server that comes with laravel

Comment: You mean that HTTP server implemented in PHP that you shouldn't use in production? However, installing the missing PHP extensions usually is a matter of knowing the correct package names and enabling them in the `php.ini` file that's being used. Note that PHP may use a different ini file for web server context or command line context. The `phpinfo()` output will print the file that's being used.

Comment: Yes please, only i am not using it in production currently, just development, i have searched for a php.ini within the project but can't seem to find it.

Comment: As I said: Run a script with the `phpinfo()` function, read it's output and search for "php.ini" in there. The location should be clearly printed.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from easyphp administration, use test code:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```